# Dynamic Google Analytics Account in GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am new to GTM and in learning phase. I wanted to implement GTM on one of the websites and requirement is that

> Based on URL, Analytics shall be sent to different GA accounts.

**Below is the example**

```
URL                       GAAccount
------------------------------------
http://domain.com/abc     UA-xxxxxabc
http://domains.com/def     UA-xxxxxdef
http://domain.com/xyx     UA-xxxxxxyz
http://domains.com/qwe     UA-xxxxxqwe
```

I tried to make **lookuptable** in GTM exactly same as mentioned above and that will operate on basis of URL but the problem here is that actual URL contains a long encrypted string as below

*http://domain.com/abc/!ut/b/dasdasd654654WEEWEXX879987xxxSSWWo_adasdw_wewqewqe*

So my lookuptable can not match URL and i get error in GTM console that `Undefined account`

I know about **Page URL** variables provided by GTM but i am not sure how to combine `Page Hostname` and `Page Path` to one Variable and then strip unwanted string from `Page Path` and match the exact URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lookup table did not work becuase it matches the entire url with your given input so it would check like
http://domain.com/abc equals to http://domain.com/abc/!ut/b/dasdasd654654WEEWEXX879987xxxSSWWo_adasdw_wewqewqe
which is obviously false

what you can do here is create a custom javascript variable that returns tracking id if your condition matches
here is an example

```
function(){

    if("{{Page URL}}".match("domain.com/abc")!==null){
        return("UA-xxxxxabc")
    }
    else if("{{Page URL}}".match("domain.com/def")!==null){
        return("UA-xxxxxdef")
    }
    else if("{{Page URL}}".match("domain.com/xyx")!==null){
        return("UA-xxxxxxyz")
    }
    else if("{{Page URL}}".match("domain.com/qwe")!==null){
        return("UA-xxxxxqwe")
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Cheers AnalyticsML

Comment: Or you write a custom variable that returns the relevant part of the url and use that in the lookup table (might be a matter of taste, but IMO that would be marginally more readable).

Comment: Yup.. that is what i was thinking write custom javascript and use in lookup.. But i had a really great confidence in Google that there might be something that i am missing.. Now i have to write my own,.

Answer (score 0):

you need 50 reps to comment :)

```
    function () { 
 var value={{Page Path}}.split("/"); 
 return value[1]; 
 }
```

Hopefully this will return only abc (I'm not sure), if it works a lookup table will do the rest :)

Comment: i want to handle GA accounts based on URL till http://domain.com/abc .. i need fill URL